# Azure Cosmos DB: Retrieving document by GUID

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have stored a document with a GUID in a Cosmos DB container. When I attempt to retrieve the same document with a `Where()` clause, however, it fails to return the document.

Here is my C# code to query document:

```cs
var application = await client
  .CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink, feedOptions)
  .Where(d => d.Id == "b0e6b18a-54rgf-497d-45g7-bcb17afbdtyh")
  .Where(d => d.Type == "application")
  .Where(d => d.DeletedDateTime == null)
  .AsDocumentQuery()
  .ExecuteNextAsync<Document>(cancellationToken)
  .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And here is a sample Json file in the Azure Cosmos DB:

```
{
    "id": "b0e6b18a-54rgf-497d-45g7-bcb17afbdtyh",
    "Type": "application",
    "ApplicationId": "b0e6b18a-54rgf-497d-45g7-bcb17afbdtyh",
    "Name": "test",
    "Description": "test application.",
    "Company": "test",
    "OwnerEmailId": "xyz@xyz.com",
    "CreatedDateTime": "",
    "ModifiedDateTime": "",
    "DeletedDateTime": null,   
    "Resources": [],
    "_rid": "removedId",
    "_self": "removedId",
    "_etag": "removedID",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1567604515
}
```

In the final output, there are no matching records. What is missing?

> **Important!** this code is working in my Development environment. But it fails in test environment.

Comment: I suppose it is because your query references "Id" while the record has the field name "id" ... check if it is case sensitive, i.e. use "d.id" instead of "d.Id". In a SQL database, this would throw an error, but CosmosDB is not relational, so it just returns an empty recordset if you have non-existing fields in your query. Let me know if that solves it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i cross checked in dev environment. could see that it works with non case sensitiveness

Comment: So I think there is a difference how you've provisioned the two CosmosDB environments - check if there is a parameter turning case-sensitiveness on or off. So that could explain why it works in DEV while it does not work in TEST. As a good practice, I suggest that you program it always as if the environment was case-sensitive, then it will always work. Also, environments should be set up identically, so the testers are able to provide the developers with reproducable test results.

Comment: @Matt - Cosmos DB doesn't have the notion of turning off case-sensitivity. Typically `Id` is mapped to `id` via NewtonSoft (e.g. `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]`).

Comment: When you say it's working in your development environment, does this mean your code works using the Cosmos DB emulator? Or do you have multiple Cosmos DB deployments? Or maybe you mean something else entirely? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: i mean, development env code connects to development  env azure cosmos db. anyway, when i replaced "id" in the where conditio with "ApplicationId". it started working. "ApplicationId" is the partition key.

Comment: not sure, may be because of timeout. result was empty.